# VB.NET Getting live status from other application

Tags: .net, vb.net

With my application i call an external commandline tool that converse iso's to other fileformats. Right now i just call the iso converter and it will run in the background, when you would run the iso converter via commandline you see what it is doing, but in my application it just runs in the background.

Right now it only gives me the status after the isoconverter is done in a textbox, how could i change this so i can see live status? like i would see in the command line tool?

This is the code that i'm calling to execute the isoconverter.

```
Private Sub GETCMD3()
    Dim CMDprocess As New Process
    Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
    StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    CMDprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
    CMDprocess.Start()
    Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = CMDprocess.StandardOutput
    Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = CMDprocess.StandardInput
    SW.WriteLine("Isoconvert.exe " & txtIsoFile.Text)
    SW.WriteLine("exit")
    txtIsoOutput.Text = SR.ReadToEnd
    SW.Close()
    SR.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current code is the line

```
txtIsoOutput.Text = SR.ReadToEnd
```

This is reading the standard output stream of the command until it is complete.  Once it is complete, it assigns the result to your text box.

What you want instead is to read from the `StreamReader` a little at a time, using `StreamReader.ReadLine` or perhaps `ReadBlock`.

Something like:

```
Dim line as String
Do
    line = SR.ReadLine()
    If Not (line Is Nothing) Then
        txtIsoOutput.Text = txtIsoOutput.Text + line + Environment.NewLine
    End If
Loop Until line Is Nothing
```

This probably won't be good enough, though. The user interface thread is now busy processing the command output, so the TextBox does not get a chance to update its display.  The easiest way to fix this is by adding `Application.DoEvents()` after modifying the text.  Make sure to disable any buttons/menus that call `GETCMD3` when `GETCMD3` starts, though.

Comment: After some testing it indeed pushes the cpu to 70%, 80% how could i resolve this with application.doevents?

Comment: You could add a call to `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` inside the loop to wait for 100 milliseconds (0.1 seconds) each time.  This will then read from the stream 10 times per second and free the CPU most of the time.  You can increase the sleep time to reduce the CPU usage if you don't need such a fast update rate.

Answer (score 1):

[Offtopic] I was reviewing your code and maybe I've found a better aproach in the way you can launch Isoconvert.exe.

If I'm not wrong, you can launch Isoconvert.exe using startinfo, without the needed of launch a console command.

```
Dim CMDprocess As New Process
Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
StartInfo.FileName = "Isoconvert.exe" 
StartInfo.Arguments = txtIsoFile.Text
CMDprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
CMDprocess.Start()
```

I think you can still read and write stdin and stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, maybe accessing process threads and checking the status?

Something like this:

```
CMDprocess.Threads(0).ThreadState = ThreadState.Running
```

Comment: Found this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173085/ but i don't know how to implement it in my code.

Comment: @PandaNL -- That link is for VB6 (you can see if you click on "APPLIES TO"), which is a totally different language from VB.NET.

Comment: Sorry. I think I missunderstand the question. My answer was a for check if the process is still alive and running.